# CQ5.5 Post to servlet using resourceType

Tags: aem

I'm doing work on an application running on an old CQ5.5 server. I've set up a servlet to do captcha verification. It has a `doGet` that provides the captcha image and a `doPost` that verifies the captcha - each method uses a different selector. The servlet is using the same resourceType as the jsp that draws the captcha form.

```
@SlingServlet(
        resourceTypes="myApp/components/myForm",
        selectors={"verify","captcha"},
        extensions={"json","png"},
        methods={"GET","POST"}
```

The servlet extends `SlingAllMethodsServlet` and I'm logged in as admin.

The GET works just fine, so the resourceType is resolving to my servlet. But the POST resolves to the default Sling servlet. Also using the "json" extension for the GET seems to result in the default GET servlet resolving.

Does version 5.5 explain this? Should I blame the old server, or is there a problem in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be associated to the specifics of the resource type. I had attempted to hook the servlet to my page component. When I instead used the resourceType of another node under the page's jcr:content node, it works as expected. I haven't tried this on another version yet, but I suspect I have never tried to use the page component node before.

Comment: can you please right what would be the url for the above servlet. I'm new in this and I didn't understand your answer.